# How to do index and match like in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use index and match like function in Pandas. I am new to this.
What I would like to do is

1. index string or multiple strings and change the corresponding price
2. index the string without regardless of uppercase and lowercase letters (a lot of the names of the fruits are in all uppercase, one uppercase and rest in lowercase, or all lowercase)

   ```
   fruits                  price
   apple from us           10
   Apple from US           11
   Mango from Canada       15
   Orange from Mexico      16
   Orange from Costa       15
   Orange from Brazil      19
   Pear from Guatemala     32
   Melon from Guatemala    4
   orange from Honduras    5
   ```

I tried 
        df.loc[df['fruits'].str.contains('apple'), 'Target Price'] = 275
but I get

```
    fruits                  price
    apple from us           275
    Apple from US           275
    Mango from Canada       275
    Orange from Mexico      275
    Orange from Costa       275
    Orange from Brazil      275
    Pear from Guatemala     275
    Melon from Guatemala    275
    Orange from Honduras    275
```

but what I would like is

```
    fruits                  price
    apple from us           275
    Apple from US           275
    Mango from Canada       15
    Orange from Mexico      16
    Orange from Costa       15
    Orange from Brazil      19
    Pear from Guatemala     32
    Melon from Guatemala    4
    Orange from Honduras    5
```

Also, the line above does not let me have multiple conditions like containing "Orange" but not from Honduras. Is there a way to only exclude if certain string is also in it so that I can change the price of Orange is set to 222 but Orange from Honduras remains as it was.

```
    fruits                  price
    apple from us           275
    Apple from US           275
    Mango from Canada       15
    Orange from Mexico      222
    Orange from Costa       222
    Orange from Brazil      222
    Pear from Guatemala     32
    Melon from Guatemala    4
    Orange from Honduras    5
```

Comment: I recommend splitting the fruits column into two columns "fruits" and "country." This will make it easier for you to filter by multiple conditions.

Comment: I simplified the column so that I can write here easier. My "fruit" columns are a much longer string and I would need to conditionally filter multiple strings.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert to lower case

```
>>> d_f.loc[d_f['Fruits'].str.lower().str.contains('apple'), 'Price'] = 275
>>> d_f
                 Fruits Price
0         apple from us   275
1         Apple from US   275
2     Mango from Canada    15
3    Orange from Mexico    16
4     Orange from Costa    15
5    Orange from Brazil    19
6   Pear from Guatemala    32
7  Melon from Guatemala     4
8  orange from Honduras     5
```